# Use a cell value in a formula

Tags: excel-formula

I need to reference a cell by (column, row) in a way where I can replace "column" with a formula to find a specific column.

`=VLOOKUP(E$25,Static!$R5:$S$10,2,FALSE)`

The result of the VLOOKUP returns the value C (for column C) I would then like to use this in a formula `=$C23`, `=$C24`, etc. to return the row values.

Comment: Does your Excel version support XLOOKUP?  If so, it returns a referene rather than a value, which you can pass to other functions.

Comment: There are probably better ways, but not knowing the whole situation and answering just this, you would use INDIRECT.  `=INDIRECT(VLOOKUP(E$25,Static!$R5:$S$10,2,FALSE) & "24")`

Comment: Once I have the column selected I need to copy the entire column, not a single value.

Comment: If you need to reference the whole column you can just use `=INDIRECT(VLOOKUP(E$25,Static!$R5:$S$10,2,FALSE) & ":" & VLOOKUP(E$25,Static!$R5:$S$10,2,FALSE))`.

Comment: Thank you - both formulas above provide the correct results.